# send the object containg list of same type of objects with to server using retrofit 2 POST

Tags: android, retrofit2

How do I send the following object to server using retrofit 2:

```
{"list":[
          {
           "addrress1":       
                       {"addressLine1":"EktaColony",
                        "addressLine2":"Warje",
                        "country":"India",
                        "state":"Maharashtra",
                        "city":"Pune",
                        "zipcode":411058},
                       },
          {address2:{.....,.....,...}}
]}
```

I am using Rxjava.

Comment: What had you tried so far?

Comment: You need to edit this question. Your question has nothing to do with retrofit but with how to unmarshall this json to a object

Answer (score 0):

You can send the json as `body` of HTTP request. Retrofit provides the annotation `@Body` for its use

So in your interface

`@POST("/yourserver/api")
Observable<ResponseType> sendReq(@Body RequestParser parser);`

Your `RequestParser` Object is the object mapped from the json string. You can use any Json serializer libraries like `gson` or `jackson` for it.

Comment: RequestParser{
@SerializedName("list")
Arraylist<Address> addressList;
}

Address{
adress fileds..
}
But how do I tell it is address 1, address 2

Comment: Can you post a valid json sample which can help to reach out at your json structure. Or put your sample json here http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and select whether you use gson or json, it will generate your pojo class which you can use to create your object

Comment: It is showing separate classes for address1, address 2... I can't create those many classes.

Comment: Can you show me a valid json example. Did you try using `@SerializeName("list") HashMap<string, Address> addressMaps` and create the `Adress` object